# Embedding a ProgressBar in the TabItem header in WPF

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, progress-bar, tabitem

The project I am working on generates a series of tabs for each item opened by the user. For some tabs in particular, certain database hits and calculations take an extended period of time. I was trying to determine a simple way to alert the user when the tab is ready and figured a progress bar would be as good or better than other ways I considered.

I am wondering if there is a way to embed a progress bar behind the header text of a TabItem or if I will need to build my own CustomControl. I have no clue how to do either, however, I think some examples of the latter exist in the project so I could try to figure that out through them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the layout of a TabItem pretty easily.  This snippet of XAML will create a TabControl with one TabItem where the header of the TabItem has a ProgressBar with a TextBlock over the ProgressBar.

Of course, please customize this XAML to actually make it look good :-D

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Grid>
                <ProgressBar Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="Some Tab"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: You can use a Grid instead of a canvas as well.

Comment: @Tyrsius Actually, I hardly ever (never) use Canvas, I just thought it was necessary to get the TextBlock on top of the ProgressBar (I don't have UI elements stacked on each other in my UI so I wouldn't know).  Looks like Grid let's you stack them as well and I always prefer a Grid to a Canvas element.

Comment: Seems to work fine, only issue I gotta work out now is the width. The TabItem is a ControlTemplate for TabControl.Resources... Or just make it a Grid and Width is handled :)

Comment: @scott.smart I personally don't use Canvas and since this works with Grid I've gone and edited my answer in case a future reader dares to use a Canvas in place of a Grid!  :-D

Comment: @docmanhattan Yes, if two items in a Grid would take up the same spot (either both being default, or both being in a specific cell), they will stack on top of each other in their Z-order. It's handy sometimes.